# Batch append DateTime and Seconds to folder name

Tags: batch-file

How would I append Date, Time, and Second to all of my folder names.

for /D %%f in (C:\Reports*) do rename "%%f" "%%~nxf"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will rename folders to the following format: `Folder Name YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM`.  Sorry no seconds resolution in batch unless you use `robocopy` or `forfiles`.  I am assuming you wanted the last modified date and time appended onto the folder name.  If you want a different date you need to specify as much.

Year = `%%V`,
Month = `%%T`,
Day = `%%U`,
Hour = `%%W`,
Minute = `%%X`, and
Meridiem = `%%Y`

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Reports"
for /D %%D in (*) do for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=/: " %%T in ("%%~tD") do rename "%%~fD" "%%~nxD %%V-%%T-%%U-%%W-%%X"
popd
```